# iPhone App that stores data from the web

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm making an iphone app that uses `NSURLConnection` to download some data from the web. I need to store this data somewhere, so my app can send out push notifications when the data changes in a particular way. For example, the data being stored is a number and a push notification will be sent out when that number changes by +-10.

I'm new to this, so I'm probably overcomplicating how I think this can be accomplished. I'm thinking I need to create a database and some server-side code that continuously pulls the data. When the data changes to my specifications (ex. +-10), it somehow pushes the data to the app which then sends out a push notification.

Is there an easier way to accomplish staying within xcode dev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app doesn't send the push notification.  The point of push notifications is your app can be in the background so it can't poll/check for a given condition (like your +-10).

When that interesting even happens server side, it can push a notification to the device.  The device can handle that notification by (1) showing text (2) playing a sound or (3) updating a badge on an icon.

So, it's not about your device downloading the data into database (although that has value for offline and occasionally connected scenarios).

So, you'll need a server side component that detects that +-10 change (on data change or polling) and then sends the push to the device.  Now, it's possible that devices are sending data to your service (uploading) and when and interesting event happens it could notify other instances of the app.

This link may help clarify push notifications:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Comment: Thank you, that helped me understand very well. Would you suggest creating the server-side component with Ruby on Rails? I've never used it before, but all I hear is great things across the web.

Comment: Server side components boil down to preference :)  Folks seem to like Asp.net MVC (C#), Ruby on Rails (Ruby fans), Django (Python), PHP and recently coming on string is node.js (with express js) which is nice because you can write server & browser in javascript.  I think it boils down to the language and platform you like ...